# Regex - Get string after last /, if that string contains something (user input)

Tags: regex

Example strings:

```
storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pictures/dog.jpeg (should be included)
storage/emulated/0/Vacation/Pictures/a-picture.jpg (shouldn't be included)
storage/emulated/0/Vacation/Pictures/mydog.jpg (should be included)
```

Example user input:

> dog

(User input cannot contain /, \n, \r, \t, \0, \f, `, ?, *, \, <, >, |, ", :, %)

I need a regular expression that checks if the string after the last `/` contains the user input.

I know that getting the string after the last `/` is done with

```
([^/]+$)
```

but I don't know anything else about regex sadly, and even that I've found on internet. Is there anyone that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
\S*/([^/\s]*dog\b\S*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2K2FC/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\S*/`: Match longest match before last `/`. `\S` matches any non-whitespace character
- `(`: Start capture group

  - `[^/\s]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `/` and not a whitespace
  - `dog\b`: Match text `dog` ending with a word boundary
  - `\S*`: Match remaining string till end
- `)`: capture group

Comment: is there any way to include mydog.jpeg as well?